# How should I use Stripe Checkout to log a 100% off transaction

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm currently using the Stripe Checkout PHP API for a website, which redirects to Stripe Checkout for payments. Everything works fine, but a new requirement from a client has arisen. The client wishes to enable their staff to "purchase" items from their website, with these transactions recorded in Stripe's logs, but without the need for credit card usage.

I attempted to address this by setting the transaction value to $0 via the API, but Stripe doesn't permit this. I then tried adding a 100% discount coupon to the transaction, which was also not allowed by Stripe. Lastly, I tried making a customer-level promo code, but again, any promo code that provided a 100% discount was not accepted by Stripe.

Do any other methods exist that would enable me to record these transactions in Stripe while allowing people to claim them for free? What's a good, creative solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible since Stripe requires a [minimum amount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-amount) of $0.50 (or equivalent in whatever currency) for a Charge to be created.

I don't think there is a way you can apply a 100% discount on a payment and process it through Stripe.  Since there's no payment there is nothing to store in Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

now you can create zero amount order with 100% off.
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/checkout/no-cost-orders